# Stop array of strings from saving with dashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm listing the models in my app so an admin can create custom roles:

```
        <% ActiveRecord::Base.send(:subclasses).each do |model| %>
    <tr>
        <td width=10>
            <label><%= check_box_tag "role[read_models][]", model.name, @role.read_models.include?(model.name) %></label><br />
        </td>
        <td width=10>
            <label><%= check_box_tag "role[write_models][]", model.name, @role.write_models.include?(model.name) %></label><br />
        </td>
        <td><%= model.name %></td>
    </tr>
    <% end -%>
```

It works great by the way. In the log it saves the array properly like so:

```
"read_models"=>["Slug", "Account", "Category", "Document", "Group", "Location", "Role", "Status", "Task", "Ticket"]
```

But when outputting the results:

```
<%= @role.read_models.each do |model| %>
   <%= model %><br />
<% end -%>
```

I get this:

```
--- 
- Slug
- Account
- Category
- Document
- Group
- Location
- Role
- Status
- Task
- Ticket
```

(Including the three dashes in the front)

I've tried doing to_a.join(', ') but it still has the dashes in front of each one.

Any ideas on how I need to change this process? Thanks!

Comment: Where is it saving like this? What are you trying to do? This is a YAML representation of the array, it has to be saved like this by Rails.

Comment: I'm seeing it in the log that it looks like an normal array but when put in the view it has the dashes.

Comment: Is there something like "to_yaml" that i can use to make it the opposite... Actually at this point it doesn't matter... it just doesn't look pretty.

Comment: There you go, answered with a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing you have a **Role** class and this class is the one used to store these values, if this is your case, here's what you could do:

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :read_models, Array
end
```

This will make ActiveRecord store these values you have at the read_models column as a YAML representation (this one you already have) but then you make **@role.read_models** you will get the Array back and not a string containing the YAML representation.